# Scala class inheritance

Tags: oop, class, scala, inheritance

Tagged as homework.
I'm having trouble in the object oriented world while trying to implement a class.

I'm implenting various functions to take action on lists, that I'm using to mock a set.
I'm not too worried about my logic on how to find union, for example, but really just the structure.

For eg:

```
abstract class parentSet[T] protected () {

    def union(other:parentSet[T]):parentSet[T]

}
```

Now I want a new class extending parentSet:

```
class childSet[T] private (l: List[T]) extends parentSet[T] {
    def this() = this(List())
    private val elems = l
    val toList = List[T] => new List(l)

    def union(other:parentSet[T]):childSet[T] = {
        for (i <- this.toList) {
            if (other contains i) {}
            else {l :: i}
        }
        return l
    }
}
```

Upon compiling, I receive errors such that type childSet isn't found in def union, nor is type T to keep it parametric. Also, I assume my toList isn't correct as it complains that it isn't a member of the object; to name a few.

Where in my syntax am I wrong?

**EDIT**

Now I've got that figured out:

```
  def U(other:parentSet[T]):childSet[T] = {
    var w = other.toList
    for (i <- this.toList) {
        if (!(other contains i)) {w = i::w}
    }
    return new childSet(w)
```

}

Now, I'm trying to do the same operations with map, and this is what I'm working on/with:

```
def U(other:parentSet[T]):MapSet[T] =  {
    var a = Map[T,Unit]
    for (i <- this.toList) {
        if (!(other contains i)) {a = a + (i->())}
    }
    return new MapSet(elems + (a->()))
  }
```

I still want to use toList to make it easily traversable, but I'm still getting type errors while messing with maps..

Answer (score 2):

This code has a few problems:

It seems that you are not realizing that `List[T]` is an *immutable* type, meaning you cannot change its value once created.  So if you have a `List[T]` and you call the `::` method to prepend a value, the function returns a new list and leaves your existing one unchanged.  Scala has mutable collections such as `ListBuffer` which may behave more like you expect.  So when you `return l`, you're actually returning the original list.

Also, you have the order wrong in using `::`.  It should go `i :: l`, since `::` is a right-binding function (because it ends with a `:`).

Lastly, in your union method you are doing `(other contains i)`.  Maybe it's just the Scala syntax that's confusing you, but this is the same as doing `(other.contains(i))` and clearly `contains` is not a defined method of `parentSet`.  It is a method on the `List[T]` type, but you're not calling `contains` on a list.

You tagged this as homework so I'm not going to fix your code, but I think you should

1. Look at some examples of correct Scala code involving lists, try [here](http://anders.janmyr.com/2009/10/lists-in-scala.html) for starters
2. Play around in the Scala REPL and try creating and working with some lists, so you get a feel for how immutable collections work.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your direct question, even though childSet is inheriting parentSet the original method specify parentSet as the return type and not childSet. You can either only use parentSet as the type OR you could specify the return type to be anything that inherits parentSet.